# Remove taxonomy terms by name, not ID with VBO

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, views

I am using a rules component with VBO to allow users to bulk remove taxonomy terms from entities. The rules takes in 2 parameters:

1. The entity type
2. The taxonomy term to be removed.

Number 2 is input by the user.  However, the taxonomy term parameter requires the id of the taxonomy term.  I need to allow the user to enter the actual taxonomy term since they will not know the id of the term.

Anyone know how to grab the taxonomy term text from the user and remove it from a list of taxonomy terms?

Thanks, 
Mickey

Comment: Term names don't have to be unique across vocabs, or even in the same vocab. Have you considered how a non-unique term name will be handled?

Comment: The rule limits the taxonomy term to a single vocabulary.